# systemd: how to trace which program launch a unit?

Tags: systemd

I test Shorewall on Debian and I see the firewall rules are enforced every 5 or 10 minutes: if I add a rule with `iptables`, the rule is deleted several minutes later.

I see no cron task, and no running program able to do it. I think the Shorewall unit is ran on a regular basis, but can not figure how.

How can I know what trigger a systemd unit? (which program, which systemd event, whatever)
In the present case, what trigger `/usr/lib/systemd/system/shorewall.service`?